# Displaying a picture on the framebuffer while running a script created with dialog

Tags: linux, embedded, framebuffer, dialog

I have setup scripts that use the dialog command. They are used to prepare embedded servers.
I'd like to display a picture on a edge while a dialog script is running. The problem is, that dialog by design effectively "flushes" what it on the screen and thus removes what was drawn on the framebuffer.

I think there might be a way to display the picture while running a such a script since e.g. some distros show a few tux penguins when booting up while displaying the boot log under them. So something like that would be nice:
a picture on the top and a useable dialog under that.

But I don't want that new embedded servers differ from existing ones and I don't want to change existing ones, so e.g. kernel recompilation or installing new software is out of question.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the switch to/from alternate screen.  You can suppress that using the **`--keep-tite`** option:

> When  built with **`ncurses`**, ***dialog*** normally checks to see if it is
>   running in an **`xterm`**, and in that case tries to suppress the initialization  strings  that would make it switch to the *alternate
>   screen*.  Switching between the normal and alternate  screens  is
>   visually  distracting  in  a  script  which  runs dialog several
>   times.  Use this option to allow ***dialog*** to use those initialization strings.

Alternatively, you could use the [`LINES`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-LINES) environment variable to ask ncurses to *not* write text on the lower lines of a screen (by telling it that there are fewer lines than actually exist).  That will stop it from writing *text* on those lines, though the effect of clearing-operations on an image is something you'd have to experiment with to see if it is useful (since the framebuffer features are mostly undocumented).  Setting [`COLUMNS`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-COLUMNS) might also seem to be useful, but that doesn't work well in practice since ncurses uses text-wrapping which wouldn't look good if the value is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think that the linux virtual terminal (whether text-mode or framebuffer) has any support for switching to and from an alternate screen. I may be wrong, but I think that the OP is after something like "force an ncurses app to use only part of the screen".

Comment: The system has no xserver and I would like to display something on the framebuffer while a dialog is running so alternate screen doesn't sound that useful.
The LINES and COLUMNS environment variables sound useful. Do they work with dialog? I will try that later.

Comment: Since I came back to this site for something else I might as well comment here what I did in the end:
I used a background script that just drew the image every 100 ms (or so. Did a stupid mistake with dd before that basically led me to asking here). Sure that way there are processing resources wasted and it has the potential to flicker for a split second when the user inputs something, but it was good enough for the government agency (main script was way worse before I worked on it and some tasks had no scripts. Now anybody could work in the department thanks to my scripts + documentation :D)